# Nodejs NetSuite-rest module : Invalid content in the request body

Tags: node.js, node-modules, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am getting this error while connecting Nodejs app to NetSuite web services :
StatusCodeError: 400 - "{"type":"https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"o:errorDetails":[{"detail":"Invalid content in the request body.","o:errorCode":"INVALID_CONTENT"}]}\n"

```
var dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

console.log('Token', process.env.token);
console.log('Token Secret', process.env.token_secret);

var NsApiWrapper = require('netsuite-rest');
NsApi = new NsApiWrapper({
   consumer_key: process.env.consumer_key,
   consumer_secret_key: process.env.consumer_secret_key,
   token: process.env.token,
   token_secret: process.env.token_secret,
   base_url: "https://xxxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com",
   realm: process.env.realm,
 });

   NsApi.request({
       path: 'query/v1/suiteql?limit=5',
       method: "POST",
       body: `{
      "q": 
           "SELECT 
           id, companyName, email, dateCreated
           FROM accounts"
       }`
      })
       .then(response => console.log(response))
       .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint that you are using uses the analytics framework and not the connect framework.  The `account` table would be closest to the `accounts` in your query, but would not contain the fields that you are looking for.  If you were looking for vendor accounts, you can use the `vendor` table:

```
select id, email, companyname, datecreated from vendor
```